# If $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{11}[x] $ then why does $f(2) = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand. I was reading through a proof and came across this.

$f(2) = 11$.

In $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$ does $11=0$? why? because the remainder when dividing 11 by 11 is 0? What would $5$ be in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x] $? Would it be 1 since 11/5 has remainder 1? How do you determine these things?

I don't remember how this works.

Thanks

Also, could you explain the fundamental ideas of these algebraic rings (that's what they're called, right?)

Comment: For 5, it should be 5/11 is zero remainder 5. So 5 mod 11 is 5. We want the remainder not the quotient.

Comment: $f(2)=2^3+2+1=11\equiv 0 \mod 11$.

Comment: For instance, $27\equiv16\equiv5\mod 11$. Etc.

Comment: Roughly, it's a ring because it's a set with some addition and multiplication, mod some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $11 = 0$. The ring $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is, in some sense, *defined* by that axiom. Everything else follows from this axiom.

Some examples:

$$15 = 11 + 4 = 0 + 4 = 4$$

$$ \frac{3}{5} = \frac{-22}{5} + 5 = (-2) \cdot \frac{11}{5} + 5
= (-2) \cdot \frac{0}{5} + 5 = 5 $$

$$3 = \frac{3}{5} \cdot 5 = 5 \cdot 5 = 25 = 11 + 11 + 3 = 3$$

---

To be more rigorous, allow me to write $[n]$ instead of $n$, when I mean to write the element of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ 'represented' by $n$. So, the first example above would be more precisely stated as $[15] = [4]$. Arithmetic works in a simple way: for example,

- $[a] + [b] = [a+b]$
- $[a] \cdot [b] = [a \cdot b]$
- $-[a] = [-a]$.

Because we can't use equality of integers to tell whether two elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ are equal, we need some other way. There is a simple-to-compute method:

> $ [x] = [y] $ if and only if $x-y$ is divisible by $11$

There is also a procedure to "normalize" a number $[n]$: use division (by $11$) with remainder to find the smallest nonnegative integer $[r]$ with the property that $[n] = [r]$.

It's interesting that we can do division in this ring too, by any nonzero element. Note that $[11]$ is zero, so we can't divide by $[11]$. It can be done in an ad-hoc method, but a systematic way is to use the extended Euclidean algorithm. You'll be introduced to this shortly. Or you could try to work it out yourself: recall that the extended Euclidean algorithm is used to find integers $a$ and $b$ such that

$$ ax + 11 b = \gcd(x, 11)$$

**Exercise:** figure out how to use the output of the extended Euclidean algorithm to compute $1 / [x]$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}_{11}$  is the ring of equivalence classes where a~b if 11|a-b. For example, $11\equiv 0 \mod 11$ since $ 11|11-0$. Hence $5 \equiv 5\equiv 16\mod 11$ (Why?). Being picky, 5 is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ but rather the equivalence class of 5 is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$. Eventually it is clear that when you write 5 you actually mean the equivalence class of $5$.